# How can I make my discord bot send messages from a .txt file (python)

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord
import os

from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
#!test1
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        await message.channel.send("<@471653134440071168> tag test")

client.run('my token')

keep_alive()
token = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
client.run(os.getenv('my token'))
```

This is my code and what I want to do is create a .txt file containing the `"<@471653134440071168> tag test"` message and make my bot read it and send that message to the text channel.

PS: im new to discord bots and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this command to send any file you want.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    with open('name.txt', 'r') as f: #if you have the file in another folder use the path instead of just the name
        msg = f.read()
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

If you want to have it as event do it like this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        with open('name.txt', 'r') as f:
           msg = f.read()
           await ctx.send(msg)
    #await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Rember that you should add `await client.process_commands(message)` if you add any commands to your bot in the future otherwise it will run only the first event.